# Forward declare HINSTANCE and friends

Tags: c++, winapi, hinstance

Is there a way to forward-declare the `HINSTANCE` type from the WinAPI without including the full (and big) `windows.h` header?

For example, if I have a class `RenderWindow` which owns an `HINSTANCE mInstance`, i will have to include `windows.h` in `RenderWindow.h`. So everything that needs `RenderWindow` also has to include `windows.h`.

I tried including `windef.h` but this seems to need some things from `windows.h`. :-( If I can't forward declare it, is there at least a portable way to use something like `long mInstance` in `RenderWindow` instead of `HINSTANCE`?

Comment: Is including windows.h actually causing you any problems?

Comment: not directly, but i don't like including it because one has to sometimes undefine `min` and `max` macros and i think it increases compile time / look up etc.

Comment: `#define NOMINMAX` before including `<windows.h>`.

Comment: I can think of a half dozen good reasons to want to avoid including it. min/max, macros of commonly used names (CreateWindow, for example), and the fact that it doesn't compile as C++. You have to enable Microsoft's language extensions. windows.h is badly behaved in every possible way.

Comment: For those landed here looking for replacement of HINSTANCE with C pointer type void * (I give up for now) there is a [heated discussion about its opacity](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/54b9f116-412f-4bf8-9012-260c56037d0a).

Comment: @abenthy you should not have min\max macros anyway. there should be  safer and perhaps even faster `std::min` \ `std::max`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HINSTANCE is declared in WinDef.h as **typedef HINSTANCE__* HINSTANCE;**

You may write in your headers:

```
#ifndef _WINDEF_
class HINSTANCE__; // Forward or never
typedef HINSTANCE__* HINSTANCE;
#endif
```

You will get compilation errors referencing a HINSTANCE when WinDef.h is not included.

Comment: That's the hack i was searching for, very clever! (`HINSTANCE__` seems to be `struct` here on MSVC2005)

Comment: It's no hack, Windef.h is written to allow it :-) Declaring a class instead of a struct guarantees a compiler error if Windef.h is included later, which means bad file structure design.

Comment: I see, but if i i use class i get a compiler error if i later include `windows.h` in my implementation file, in which i need `windows.h`. Is it bad file structure to use you're suggested typedef in a header file and include `windows.h` in the corresponding source file?

Comment: If you need Windows.h in *this* compilation unit, include it at first, as other library headers, before your own.

Comment: Sorry to tumbleweed this, but I am having problems using it (and need it!) - I am trying to compile some C code on *nix. Using this excellent solution leads to `error: unknown type name 'class'`. My C is poor :\ @AlainRist

Comment: @jtlz2 ask a separate question

Comment: That'd invoke undefined behavior. `HINSTANCE__` is a [reserved identifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers#In_declarations). If that snippet of code is included anywhere: the result of compilation is, by definition, [NOT A PROGRAM](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). 

I know nobody cares. Call me nobody. (I also read terms and conditions)

Answer (score 5):

You could declare it void* and cast the errors away.  This is close to a never-ending battle though, sooner or later you'll get tripped up.  Use pre-compiled headers so you don't care about the size of windows.h

stdafx.h:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
```

Answer (score 3):

> For example, if I have a class `RenderWindow` which owns an `HINSTANCE mInstance`, i will have to include `windows.h` in `RenderWindow.h`. So everything that needs `RenderWindow` also has to include `windows.h`.

Have you looked at the [Pimpl idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer)? This allows you to hide private members. A side-effect is that you don't have to include their headers in your class' header.

Comment: Yup, Pimpl is how I usually do this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I never the less have to say that i prefer Alain Rist's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hey @NoSenseEtAl I guess we are still there.

In 2021, `HINSTANCE` is defined in `<minwindef.h>`. Including directly `<minwindef.h>` gives the error: "No Target Architecture"

To work around the error, do the following (assuming building for x64):

```c
#define _AMD64_
#include <minwindef.h>

int main() {
    HINSTANCE h;
}
```

Note that the macro `_AMD64_` is not documented, it starts with underscore, so not to be defined by user.

And it is defined only by `<Windows.h>`, so there's no smaller header to include make it defined.

Apparently there's more hope that Windows SDK will work fine with Modules, so can fix the build speed by Modules instead.

Answer (score 1):

The best portable way to deal with handles without header including is `reinterpret_cast`ing them to a type with exactly the same size.

Most handles have pointer size<sup>1</sup>. So `void*` or `uintptr_t` will do. Examples:

- `_beginthreadex` returns `uintptr_t` instead of `HANDLE` to a thread.
- MSVC `thread::native_handle` returns `void*`

Be sure to `static_assert` for type sizes in a place where you see the type.

<sup>1</sup> Few handles don't have pointer size, I can only recall the one returned by `AcquireCredentialsHandle`.